# Import .t3d file

Tags: linux, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I try to import a .t3d file but it seems like there is no default upload folder specified.

[image: default upload folder]

I did my research but I was not able to find out where I can specify this path, I don't understand why such a folder is even necessary?

Can someone tell me how I can fix this so I can import t3d files?

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a new folder under:

```
fileadmin/user_upload/_temp_/importexport/
```

This is where the export tool is exporting the .t3d files

Comment: But i need to import t3d file, not export it. Are you sure?

Comment: The folder is just to place temporary the file into the server then you can proceed with the import

Comment: So this means that i need to be on the server to import something? I can't connect to the typo3 backend from somewhere else and upload it?

Comment: If you have enough permission you can also create it through the filelist module in backend.

For sure the problem you have is either a missing upload folder or you do not have enough permission into the server.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your hints, i will test it tomorrow and report back